# Using Pandas to rename files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to rename files using an excel sheet and pandas but I keep getting an IO error. In the 'Filename' column I have the original filename along with what I want it to be in the 'rename' column. I know there are other ways to do this but I don't understand why the below doesn't work.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from os.path import join
import shutil

dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
excelFile = join(dir,'test.xlsx')
output_image_dir = os.path.join(dir,'PREAPPROVAL')  
df = pd.read_excel(excelFile, sheetname='rename')


for x,y in zip(df['Filename'].astype('str'),df['rename']):
    x = join(output_image_dir,x)
    y = join(output_image_dir,y)
    shutil.move(x,y)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\1. Projects\2. Python\2. X1\rename_images.py", line 26, in <module>
    shutil.move(x,y)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Dropbox\\1. Projects\\2. Python\\2. X1\\PREAPPROVAL\\VERT.jpg'
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: Put a `print` of `x` and `y` before the rename, to see if the paths make sense.

Comment: Did you try printing `x` just before `shutil.move` and check whether its a valid file or not?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I did print x first. I even tried it with a list comprehension [f for f in listdir(outputimagedir)] replacing the first part of my zip and it worked fine. I printed the name from the dataframe and compared it to the list comprehension and it looked identical.

Comment: Does the directory where the file is being moved to already exist?

Comment: Yes it does. I used list comprehension and completed the shutil.move. I copy and pasted the filenames from said folder into excel and tried it with pandas but keep getting errors.

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I added it to my post.

Comment: `shutil.move` moves the files, so most probably the files are already moved as you said in your comment . Now they no longer exist. Did you check whether it really exists or not?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes the files really exist. When I shutil.move using the list comprehension the files are properly renamed. I then delete those files and repopulate the folder with the same files before they were renamed. The columns in the excel sheet are literally me copy and pasting the output of the list comprehension. I wonder if this has something to do with the dtype of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, but I figured it out. There was an extra space in one of the filenames that threw everything off. Thanks.